# If two circles meet at a unique point, then the line through their centers passes through that point

Tags: geometry, circles

> Let two circles meet at a unique point: M. Prove (or disprove) that the line joining their centers passes through M.

**My attempt:**

$T_1$ is tangent for $C_1$ and will meet $C_1$ at a single point $M$.

$T_2$ is tangent for $C_2$ and will meet $C_2$ at a single point $M$.

BUT:

Will $T_1$ meet $C_2$ at single point $M$, or two points? How can we prove it is a single point?

Similarly: Will $T_2$ meet $C_1$ at single point $M$, or two points?

Prove for any general two circles satisfying the property that they meet at a single point.

Comment: Reflect the figure at the line joining the centres. What happens to $M$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen please provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: reflect $M$ in the line joining the centres to some $M'$.  Is $M'$ on both circles?

Comment: how to do this for a general circle

Comment: What was the reason to duplicate Hagen von Eitzen's comment?

Comment: @rtybase I didn't see Hagen's comment when I typed that.  My workflow consists of opening many tabs and slowly work through them, so comments do not necessarily appear "on time".

Comment: @Sid what do you mean by "a general circle"?  You have two circles $C_1,C_2$ given to you.

Comment: how do i find the equation of that line joining centers?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** assume it's a different point and use the triangle inequality.